# Changes to cache changes list object c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, caching

I have a cache method as follows:-

**EDIT**

```
    // Cache Methods
    public void dbcTvShowsList(ref List<TvShow> listTvShows, ref Int16 err)
    {
        // Check to see if tv shows are already in cache
        if (HttpRuntime.Cache["TvShows"] != null)
        {
            listTvShows = (List<TvShow>)HttpRuntime.Cache["TvShows"];

            // Make sure we have data in the list
            if (listTvShows.Count == 0)
            {
                // No data in the list. Read it from the database
                // Now cache the data
            }
            else
            {
                // Now cache the data
                HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert("TvShows", listTvShows, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(3), System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Data no longer in cache. Read it from the database

            // If we got data, cache it
            if (err == 0)
            {
                HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert("TvShows", listTvShows, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(3), System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
            }
        }
    }
```

Now in my class i am reading that cached data and then makin some changes to it. But that is affecting my cached data as follows:-

```
new iNGRID_Data.TvShows.DataMethods().dbcTvShowsList(ref _TvShows, ref err);
TvShow TvShowAll = new TvShow();
TvShowAll.ShowId = 0;
TvShowAll.ShowName = "All Programming";
_TvShows.Add(TvShowAll);
```

This modifies the global cache and adds All Programming to it.

Can you please let me know why is that happening?

Regards
Abhishek

Comment: You only have a reference to the list. It's not a copy.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are passing the list in via the `ref` keyword. You aren't working with a local/new copy of the list but a reference to the list you passed in. Not sure why `ref` is even needed here to be honest.

Also, your logic and comments seem a bit off:

```
// Make sure we have data in the list
if (listTvShows.Count == 0)
{
     // No data in the list. Read it from the database
}
else
{
     // Now cache the data
     HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert("TvShows", listTvShows, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(3), System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
}
```

You check if you have data, and if not fetch from database but aren't inserting it into the cache (presumably).

Then in your else you state that you insert the data into the cache, why? What this code does is essentially insert your data into the cache if it already exists. Surely you want the opposite of that? E.g.

```
if(listTvShows.Count == 0)
{
    //fetch from db
    //insert into cache
}

//no need for an else, do whatever you need with the data
```

Comment: listTvShows could also be null, if the key does not exist.

Comment: I tried this too. That modifies the data of global cache. The answer seems to be different from the question I asked.

Comment: @scheien Yep - We always null check in our cache layer.

Comment: @DGibbs See the above edit. I am using that question and ref keyword is a predefined pattern I use in my codes. I cannot change the ref keyword.
My question asks why is the cache being modified?

Comment: @vishal Do you know what the `ref` keyword does? Why are you using it?